# Linq List contains specific values

Tags: linq

I need to know if the List I am working with contains **only** some specific values.

```
var list = new List<string> { "First", "Second", "Third" };
```

If I want to know if the List contain at least one item with the value "First" I use the **Any** keyword:

```
var result = list.Any(l => l == "First");
```

But how I can write a Linq expression that will return true/false only if the List contains "First" and "Second" values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but if you want to ensure that "First" and "Second" are represented once, you can do:

```
var result = list.Where(l => l == "First" || l =="Second")
                 .Distinct()
                 .Count() == 2;
```

or:

```
var result = list.Contains("First") && list.Contains("Second");
```

If you've got a longer "whitelist", you could do:

```
var result = !whiteList.Except(list).Any();
```

On the other hand, if you want to ensure that *all* items in the list are from the white-list *and* that *each* item in the white-list is represented at least once, I would do:

<s>var set = new HashSet(list);
    set.SymmetricExceptWith(whiteList);
    var result = !set.Any();</s>

**EDIT**: Actually, Jon Skeet's `SetEquals` is a much better way of expressing the last bit.

Comment: What does it happen if I write here something like:
list = new List<String> { "First", "First", "Second" }

Will it return true anyway?

Comment: @Raffaeu: Yes, all 3 samples I've provided will return true.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot, I personally like the First one syntax, it is more SQLish

Answer (score 4):

Your question is unclear.

From the first sentence, I'd expect this to be what you're after:

```
var onlyValidValues = !list.Except(validValues).Any();
```

In other words: after you've stripped out the valid values, the list should be empty.

From the final sentence, I'd expect this:

```
var validSet = new HashSet<string>(requiredValues);
var allAndOnlyValidValues = validSet.SetEquals(candidateSequence);
```

Note that this will still be valid if your candidate sequence contains the same values multiple times.

If you could clarify *exactly* what your success criteria are, it would be easier to answer the question precisely.

Comment: @Raffaeu: Please see my edit - basically, your question can currently be read in very different ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intersect` to find matches:

```
var list = new List<string> { "First", "Second", "Third" }; 
var comparelist = new List<string> { "First", "Second" };

var test = list.Intersect(comparelist).Distinct().Count() == comparelist.Count();
```