# compare list type year's value with datetime column in linq to sql query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

i have linq to sql query which i am using to bind grid

```
var query = (from bottom in
                                 (from d in context.tbl_pl_data
                                  where (d.lng_clientid.Equals(ClientId) && d.str_name.Equals(name) && d.int_deleted.Equals(0))
                                  orderby d.dte_mod_on descending
                                  select d).AsEnumerable()
                             select new tbl_pl_data
                                        {

                                            lng_id = bottom.lng_id,
                                            str_itemdsc = bottom.str_itemdsc,
                                            dte_cr_on = bottom.dte_cr_on,
                                            str_cr_by = bottom.str_cr_by,
                                            str_mod_by = bottom.str_mod_by,
                                            dte_mod_on = bottom.dte_mod_on
                                        }).ToList().OrderByDescending(d=>d.dte_mod_on).ToList();
```

Now i want to show this data according to year.
I have session that has value of year.. value could be null or list type having single year or multiple year..i mean 2009 or 2009 and 2010. I am getting years value from below session.

```
Session["UserYearSelected"] = model.str_year_selected.Split(',').ToList();
```

Now how do i change my above query so that it accepts null or list of year value and compare with dte_cr_on column which is datetime and show data for that particular years only

Comment: no one here to help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Demon for link..it helped me to solve problem.. here is the solution

```
string[] split=new string[]{};
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserYearSelected"] != null)
            {
                split = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserYearSelected"].ToString().Split(',');
            }
var query = (from anode in
                             (from d in context.tbl_pl_data
                              where (d.lng_clientid.Equals(ClientId) && d.str_name.Equals(name) && d.int_deleted.Equals(0) && (split.Length==0 || split.Contains(d.dte_cr_on.Year.ToString())))
```

Comment: Good stuff, glad you got it sorted! Remember to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this and recon you need something along the lines of:

```
from d in context.tbl_pl_data
where (d.lng_clientid.Equals(ClientId) && d.str_name.Equals(name) && d.int_deleted.Equals(0)
      && d.dte_cr_on.Year.Contains(Session["UserYearSelected"])
```

If there's multiple years however, you'll probably need to convert `Session["UserYearSelected"]` into a `string[]`

Obviously can't test your query or check it compiles but hopefully it'll help you.

You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616736/linq-list-contains-specific-values) for further help.

Comment: Hi let me give me example....I have session that has values 2009,2010,2012 and i have split in this value in array of string by this code string[] split = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserYearSelected"].ToString().Split(',');  So now i have list of array . Now contains work for 1 value but i have multiple value .How do i get data for multiple year ?